# Find all variables used in a shell script

Tags: shell, token, lex

I'm trying to write a program that finds all variables **used** in a shell script (note; used, not declared). e.g., if I give it something like this:

```
cdo_verbosity() {
        if [ "x$CDO_QUIET" == "x1" ]; then
                cdo="cdo -s"
        elif [ "x$CDO_VERBOSE" == "x1" ]; then
                cdo="cdo -v"
        else
                cdo=cdo
        fi
}
```

I would get back a list of:

```
CDO_QUIET
CDO_VERBOSE
```

I've found a few posts that recommend something like this:

```sh
function extract_variables() {
        script=$1
        echo "Extracting variables from $script"
        ( set -o posix; set ) > /tmp/variables.before
        source $script
        ( set -o posix ; set ) >/tmp/variables.after
        diff /tmp/variables.before /tmp/variables.after > variables_defined_in_${script}.dat
        rm /tmp/variables.before /tmp/variables.after
}
```

However, that seems to work only for variables that are declared rather than used. Note that the input script has all sort of shell-isms, e.g. `${var:-default}`, `$var`, `${var_with_words}`, `eval ${nested_${var}}`, so it's not necessarily as simple as "find everything with a $"

Target language for the solution program is arbitrary, but I'd prefer to write it in shell or Python...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is it acceptable to run the script? (Not saying that I have a solution either way, but it seems like it makes a big difference... running an arbitrary script could be considered a bit reckless but if you're going to run the script anyway it wouldn't be an additional problem.)

Comment: In principle yes (it comes from a trusted source). That would enable me to use the solution I posted that compares environments before and after, but I can't guarantee that all the functions needed would actually be run, so if some function defines a variable and exports it to the environment, and it isn't run, I'd be missing that one.

Comment: If you are relying on executing the code to know what it does, you will not discover anything about parts of the code which are not executed :-). The snippet you include also fails to find existing variables whose values were modified, or variables whose values were only read (in the particular execution of the script, which might have modified the variables under different circumstances).

Comment: Honestly, I don't believe there is any way to discover the names of variables which might under some unknown circumstances be used (or even just modified) by parts of a script which happen not to be executed under current circumstances. `Eval` could do just about anything. (And even if you don't use `eval` explicitly, there are lots of effective equivalents, including arithmetic evaluation, `${!indirect}` and `declare -n`. Asking a program to guess what these things might do (or even if they might happen) seems tantamount to solving the Halting Problem.